# Load balancing and Auto-Scaling best practices

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

If I have 2 AZ’s, with a web server in each, fronted by an ELB and Route53 DNS then what’s the best way to balance load and manage failover?

1. If you set the R53 routing policy to be weighted round robin does that over-ride the ELB in terms of choosing which AZ to use? Or if you use R53 failover, will the ELB still send traffic evenly between healthy AZ’s and R53 would ensure it routes to a healthy ELB if one AZ goes out?
2. In terms of auto healing (if an AZ goes out) am I better to attach an ASG to the ELB and let that manage spinning up servers in one AZ if the other went out? Or run that ASG in isolation (i.e. not associated with the ELB). What’s the benefit/disadvantages of either?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Route53 record should be an alias to the ELB. To use a Route53 routing policy in this case you would have to create DNS records pointing to each EC2 instance, which would completely bypass the ELB.
2. Setup an Autoscaling Group that is attached to your ELB. This way when new instances are created via Autoscaling events they will be automatically added to the ELB instance pool and start receiving traffic. Without attaching the ASG to the ELB the newly created instances would never receive any traffic.

Comment: Thanks Mark, so when aliased to an ELB does the R53 routing policy not matter? Or will it still manage failover etc  if an ELB in an AZ goes out ?

Comment: You should enable cross-zone load balancing in your ELB. Then the ELB will exist multiple AZs, so a single zone failure shouldn't impact your ELB. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/enable-disable-crosszone-lb.html